# Single gesture to mark a message as read/unread in iOS 13?

Tags: ios

I updated to iOS 13 recently and discovered that I can not swipe right on a message in the messages app to mark a message as read or unread. Is there a quick single gesture to mark a message as read/unread like in the mail app?

I know there’s a multiple tap way of marking messages as read, but I’m not asking about that. But even that 3-tap method of marking a message as read does not allow you to mark a message as unread, which is an astounding oversight to me.

I feel like I’ve tried everything. Am I missing something?

Comment: it works for me in new iOS . The single gesture from left to right on the top of the message allows me to mark it as Read/UnRead message.

Comment: I don’t care if the sender gets a read receipt. That’s not why I want to mark a message as unread. Besides, I have send read receipts disabled.

Comment: You sure you’re not referring to the Mail app @Udhy?